# In Hibernate, how do I create a Criteria-restriction object with a function operation trunc on a column name?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

```sql
select * from tableA where trunc(order_date) > sysdate -7;
```

Something like

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TableA.class).
add(Restrictions.gt("orderDate", afterSubtracting7DaysFromToday));
```

Comment: `sysdate` is a proprietary feature of Oracle and hence, will not be available in Hibernate. Executing a native query will be one of the options.

Comment: Thanks, but not just sysdate, but trunc function, how do i get it in the code? Sysdate anyways I handled using Date object.

Comment: As stated earlier, proprietary features are not supported by ORM frameworks though in case of functions, there are some common supported functions such as those group functions like `max()`, `min()`, `sum()`, `count()` and other common functions like `trim()`, `between()` etc which `trunc()` is not part of.

Comment: Not sure about Hibernate criteria but in JPA criteria, you could use [`CriteriaBuilder#function(String name, Class<T> type, Expression<?>... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-) in order to create an expression to execute a native database function. You will find the equivalent to this in JPQL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlRestriction to execute sql database functions.
Something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TableA.class).
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc(order_date) > sysdate -7"));
```